# Is there a combinatorial representation of general topological manifolds similar to triangulations?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, manifolds, simplicial-complexes, triangulations

Piece-wise linear manifolds are combinatorially represented by simplicial complexes modulo Pachner moves. However, for dimensions greater than $3$, the notions of piece-wise linear and topological manifolds are inequivalent, and there are manifolds with no, or with many inequivalent triangulations.

$n$-dimensional simplicial complexes can be represented by a graph where the $n$-simplices are the nodes and $n$-simplices sharing common $n-1$-simplices are connected by edges. The triangulation carries a branching structure which additionally allows us to order the $n+1$ edges incident to every node.

Is there a similar combinatorial representation for general topological manifolds? Ideally, I'd like something "graph-like" with pieces representing "local parts" of the manifold glued together in some way, subject to a finite set of moves. But I'm also interested in other combinatorial representations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition

Comment: So, is there a way to deal with handle decompositions combinatorially? I guess, if you have a combinatorial representation of $n$-manifolds, you can construct a combinatorial representation of the surface and attaching sphere in every step of a handle decomposition of a $n+1$-manifold?

Comment: But I have no idea what a set of moves could be that maps between different handle decompositions of the same manifold. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Also, aren't handle decomposition defined for smooth manifolds only (which are, to my limited knowledge, somewhere between PL and general topological manifolds)?

Comment: They are defined and powerful also in the PL setting, see this classical book of Rourke and Sanderson https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540111023

Comment: Handle decompositions for all topological manifolds except in dimension 4. The proof is basically to use local smooth charts to inductively build up a handle decomposition, and then whenever you move to a new chart you use concordance extension to kind of align the handle decomposition in the new chart.